# Need help troubleshooting paramiko issue

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I can ssh to a server using pexpect and have no problems logging in and running commands. However, I would like to switch to using paramiko to make the ssh connections so I can take advantage of some of the other paramiko modules. However, when I use paramiko I get the error:

```
sock.connect((hostname, port))
  File "<string>", line 1, in connect
socket.error: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

I don't understand why it says no route to host, as I can definitely reach the node as pexpect showed me or by just simply ssh'ing to the node.

Any help in what might be the issue here would be greatly appreciated. I am not sure how to even go about troubleshooting this.

I am running paramiko with debugs enabled like this, but I don't get any debug messages and the script just fails immediately:

```
paramiko.common.logging.basicConfig(level=paramiko.common.DEBUG)
```

Comment: I am not sure but if you try to ssh in verbose mode may be it might help

Comment: Just because your old `pexpect` code works doesn't mean you don't have a value error in this new script (consider `hostname`). Before you make the connection, could you print out the values of `hostname` and `port` as well as the variable types and edit into this question?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you could post a simplified example of the code you're using.

Check to make sure that name resolution is happening properly:

```
socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
```

Also, I'm not sure why you're using `socket` directly? Or is that part of the stacktrace and error message you get when you

You should be able to accomplish what you want with something like this:

```
from paramiko.client import SSHClient
client = SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect('ssh.example.com')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls -l')
print stdout
```

It would be more helpful if you supplied the full error message, stacktrace, and the code that you're using.